# C++ subscript operator about map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, operator-keyword

recently, I was confused by subscript operator about map. For example
, the code looks like below

```
#include <map>

class A{
public:
    int a;
    A(){cout << "default constructor" <<endl;}
    A(int a){
        cout << "user_defined constructor" <<endl;
        this->a = a;
    }
    A(const A& tmp){
        cout << "copy constructor" <<endl;
        this->a = tmp.a;
    }
    A& operator= (const A& tmp){
        cout << "assign constructor" <<endl;
        this->a = tmp.a;
        return *this;
    }

};
int main(){
    std::map<int, A> m;
    m[1] = A(1);  // error occur  right?
    m.insert (make_pair(1,A(1)));   // ok
}
```

I want know what happened when we write the code.

```
m[1] = A(1); // it will first make a empty pair ? right? 

m.insert (make_pair(1,A())); // here call default constructor
```

and then call  Assignment constructor or copy  constructor?
the output is

```
user_defined constructor
default constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
assign constructor
```

Can you  explain to me the detail, thanks a lot.

Comment: `A` is not default constructible, it cannot the value of a `map`

Comment: @KABoissonneault: Yes it can be. You just can't use `operator[]` in that case.

Comment: What kind of "details" do you need?

Comment: @ KABoissonneault If there is a default constructor of A , we can write m[1] = A(1);

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Interesting. Kind of like how you can use move-only types in a vector, just not `vector::push_back`. I feel like those "implicitely dynamic API changes" are not very well documented

Comment: @KABoissonneault care to elaborate on move-only types in a vector? This sounds to me like you misunderstood something there.

Comment: @KABoissonneault: There's no API change. Simply any template function, or member function of  a template class, is not compiled (other than checking for syntax) if it is not used. Also, you can use `vector::push_back` with move-only types, because there is an overload which takes an r-value reference.

Comment: Look, I'll just stop posting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
m[1] = A(1);
```

First the map looks for an entry with a key of `1`. If it doesn't find one, it then tries to create a new entry with that key, along with a default constructed `A` object. Since your `A` class is not default constructible, this fails to compile.

But assuming that wasn't the case, a reference to this newly created `A` object (or a reference to the one that was already there, if the key was found) is returned. This all happens with the `m[1]` expression. The rest of your statement, `= A(1)`, creates a new `A` object and assigns it to the reference which was returned from `m[1]`.

Comment: So you means : it will first call A's default constructor and then call A's user-defined constructor and finally can A's Assignment constructor right?

Comment: @ArthurGeorge: Yes. Although the order of the default constructor call and the explicit call to `A(1)` is implementation defined. It may be reversed.

Comment: thanks @Benjamin Lindley. But when I add some test code to the  segment code above. the output result is:  A's user_defined constructor -->A's default constructor --> A's copy constructor --> A's copy constructor --> A's assign constructor .  Yes ,oneuser_defined constructor one default constructor ;two copy constructor ; and one assign constructor

Comment: @ArthurGeorge: Yes, there may be also be an unspecified number of copy constructor calls, or move constructor calls in the process of placing the object into the map. By the way, the assignment operator is not a constructor.

Comment: "an unspecified number of copy" means the copy constructor maybe not 2 ? I really want to know why there are several  copy constructor ? any link to help me ? thank you a lot

Comment: @ArthurGeorge: The insertion will look something like this: `insert(std::make_pair(1, A()))`. Without optimizations, that will first copy the default constructed `A` into a pair, then this pair will be copied into the node of the map. There could be more than 2 copies (the standard does not forbid it), but I don't see why there ever would be. There could also be fewer copies, and if your class has a move constructor, that can be used instead.

Comment: thank you. It was so late yesterday, so I had to go to sleep ☺ You have solved my confusion. By The way, can you recommend me some books to learn c++? Similar problem always bothers me. Thank you agin.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what functions are called, just set breakpoints on them in a debugger. You will see that `m[1] = A(1);` calls in order

1. constructor `A(int)`
2. default constructor `A()` (which you must add to compile)
3. `A& operator=(const A& other)`

So what happens is pretty clear : it first constructs your `A(1)`, then searches for key 1 in the map, fails to find it so inserts a default `A` on it, and finally replaces it by your `A(1)`.

Mind this happens on a debug build. A release build can be [optimized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) to avoid some of the operations above. Add prints in those functions to be completely sure.

If you want to minimize the number of copies, use `m.emplace(1,1)` instead of `m[1] = A(1)`. It will only call the constructor `A(int)`, neither the default constructor, nor the assignment operator.

Comment: thanks , I just and some prints, and it output like   A's user_defined constructor -->A's default constructor --> A's copy constructor --> A's copy constructor --> A's assign constructor .

Comment: So do you have the answer to your question ?

Comment: your idea about setting  breakpoints  using debugger is really helpful, By the way, The reason why there are two copy constructor is  answered by @Benjamin Lindley.  thanks again.

Comment: Mind the copy elisions in release builds (I included a link in the answer above), the only way to be sure is using prints. Also, if you want the least number of constructions, use `emplace` (also added above).